# TypeError while operating on list indices in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, typeerror, slice

I have the following code:

```
(len(parameters) / 2
```

The code above returned the error:

```
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

Why is this the case - especially the length of the vector I gave is an int which is divisible by 2 (in fact, I check for this)?

I would think integers have exact representations in python, so len(a)/2 should always return an int.

Any help is this matter is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`len(a)/2` is floor division.

**It always returns a float.**

You should do `integer division //`

```
parameters[: (len(parameters) // 2)]
```

Example

```
4/2

2.0

4//2

2
```

Comment: was there a change from python 2 to python regarding the convention surrounding / or am i hallucinating?

Comment: @Lost1 Yes, in Python 2 if you divide two ints you would get an int regardless of the remainder.

Answer (score 1):

Even if the `parameters` is divisible by 2 without a remainder, the `len(parameters)/2` will return a `float`. Use `len(parameters)//2` to cast it into an `int`.

For more information; [Numeric Types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex).

Comment: congrats for the first gold !!

Comment: you're welcome.. keep it up!!